# Why does calling setValue within my custom Slider Class cause this program to crash?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

This is going to seem a little silly but please follow me if you can:

```
class Slider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Slider(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void updateValue(int value) { setValue(value);}
    int get() const { return value(); }
};
```

Simply put, I am just trying to update the value of the custom slider via a controller (I know, I can do this with slots by doing `ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(int);`).

I have a `Controller<T....> controller(t&...)`, which takes an arbitrary number of Classes and allows me to set their values and get their values, for example:

```
Controller<CustomSlider,CustomSpinBox,MyClass> controller(*ui->horizontalSlider,*ui->spinBox,myClass);
```

So what I do with the slot, is tell the controller to update all of the values like so:

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    controller.setValues(value);
    getValues();
}
```

`getValues()` simply outputs to the console to tell me that they have indeed all updated.

`setValues(int)` calls the function `updateValue(int)` which calls each classes setter function. It should be a straight forward update, however whenever I try to move the slider the program crashes and the debugger doesn't really give me anything useful other than crashing on `qabstractslider.cpp` line 531 `Q_D(QAbstractSlider)`. So I don't really know what is going on with this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I should mention that, `ui->horizontalSlider` has been promoted to a `Slider`class.

**EDIT2**: Asked to make a MVE, so here is what I can do:

```
#ifndef TESTCONTROLLER_HPP
#define TESTCONTROLLER_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "slider.hpp"
#include "spinbox.hpp"
#include "controller.hpp"
#include "myclass.hpp"

namespace Ui {
class TestController;
}

class TestController : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestController(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~TestController();

    void getValues();
    void print(const std::vector<int> &p);

private slots:
    void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value);
    void on_spinBox_valueChanged(int arg1);

private:
    Ui::TestController *ui;

    MyClass myClass;

    Controller<Slider,SpinBox,myClass> controller;
};

#endif // TESTCONTROLLER_HPP
```

TestController.cpp:

```
#include "testcontroller.hpp"
#include "ui_testcontroller.h"

TestController::TestController(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TestController),
    controller(*ui->horizontalSlider,*ui->spinBox,myClass)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

TestController::~TestController()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TestController::getValues()
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    controller.getValues(values);
    print(values);
}

void TestController::print(const std::vector<int> &p)
{
    for(const auto & e: p)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


void TestController::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    controller.setValues(value);
    getValues();
}

void TestController::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int arg1)
{
    controller.setValues(arg1);
    getValues();
}
```

controller.hpp:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_HPP
#define CONTROLLER_HPP

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename...Classes>
class Controller
{
  public:
    Controller(Classes&...objects) : objects(objects...){}
    Controller(std::tuple<Classes&...> tup) : objects(tup){}

    void setValues(int value)
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (x.updateValue(value),...);}, objects);
    }

    void getValues(std::vector<int> &values) const
    {
      std::apply([&](auto&...x) { (values.push_back(x.get()),...);}, objects);
    }

    std::tuple<Classes&...> getObjects() const
    {
      return objects;
    }

  private:
    std::tuple<Classes&...> objects;
};

template<typename...ClassesL, typename...ClassesR>
auto operator+(const Controller<ClassesL...>& lhs, const Controller<ClassesR...>& rhs)
{
  return Controller(std::tuple_cat(lhs.getObjects(),rhs.getObjects()));
}

template<typename...ClassesL, typename ClassesR>
auto operator+(const Controller<ClassesL...> &lhs, ClassesR rhs)
{
  Controller<ClassesR> makeController(rhs);
  return Controller(std::tuple_cat(lhs.getObjects(),makeController.getObjects()));
}

template<typename ClassesL, typename...ClassesR>
auto operator+(ClassesL lhs, const Controller<ClassesR...> &rhs)
{
  Controller<ClassesL> makeController(lhs);
  return Controller(std::tuple_cat(makeController.getObjects(),rhs.getObjects()));
}

#endif // CONTROLLER_HPP
```

With all of this, you will simply need to copy the Slider Class, and in the .cpp file you will need to do `Slider::Slider(QWidget *parent) : QSlider(parent)`. Spin Box class looks exactly the same as slider, other than it inherits from `QSpinBox`, then MyClass has their own getters and setters, however `updateValue` and `get` must be included as well.

You then need to add a horizontal slider and a spinbox in the design, promote both of the sliders to the classes that I have provided, and you should be good to replicate the issue.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I will do my best, however bear with me as this is going to make this code base a lot bigger.

Comment: For me there is no problem about the time it takes to provide what I have asked, the problem is yours because if the time is too long your question can be closed. You should take the time to do it before asking your question since I think it is easy to deduce that the problem is in your implementation

Comment: @eyllanesc I have provided everything needed to replicate the program. I usually have no issues with providing a MCVE, however, I don't really know how to provide them since most of the programs are huge so I try to get them down as small as possible and track down where the issue is. It's obvious that it is somewhere in my implementation, which is why I have tracked the problem down the the `updateValues` function in `Slider`. This problem is the same with the `SpinBox` class.

Comment: @eyllanesc, did you erase you comment? I think you may have been up to something about the pointer. However, why wouldn't passing it by reference work? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: An error that I see is that QObjects as widgets are not copyable, that's what I meant

Comment: @ellyanesc, and that is because I am deferencing them with *?

Comment: I put together a much simplified mcve (all plain old C++ rather than UI file) and it appears to behave as expected.  The fact that your debugger points to `Q_D(QAbstractSlider)` as the offending line is rather suspicious -- suggests that the `this` pointer may not be valid at that point.  Can you compile with maximum debug info and optimization disabled and try to get a call stack at the point of failure --assuming you haven't already done so of course.

Comment: @G.M. I will go ahead and do so.